# How would I list owners and permissions for all directories named X recursively?

Tags: command-line-interface, ls, recursive

Basically I would like to do a 'ls -l' recursively showing only those directories named web. How would I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like:

```
$ find /path/to/files -name "web* -type d | xargs ls -la
```

Comment: With some tweaking this worked well.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -lR | grep -w web
```

`-R` List subdirectories recursively
`-w` Select  only  those lines containing matches that form whole words.